# Finding the difference between values with the same name in a merged CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need to find the difference between values with the same names.
I have two csv files that I merged together and placed in another csv file to have a side by side comparison of the number differences.

Below is the sample merged csv file:

```
Q1Count             Q1Names               Q2Count                   Q2Names
2                     candy                     2                     candy
9                     apple                     8                     apple
10                    bread                     5                 pineapple
4                      pies                    12                     bread
3                   cookies                     4                      pies
32                chocolate                     3                   cookies
[Total count: 60]                               27                 chocolate
NaN                     NaN                     [Total count: 61]
```

All the names are the same (almost), but I would like to have a way to make a new row space for the new name that popped up under `Q2Names`, `pinapple`.

Below is the code I implemented so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
    
Q1ReportsDir='/path/to/Q1/Reports/'
Q2ReportsDir='/path/to/Q2/Reports/'

Q1lineCount = f'{Q1ReportsDir}Q1Report.csv'
Q2lineCount = f'{Q2ReportsDir}Q2Report.csv'

merged_destination = f'{Q2ReportsDir}DifferenceReport.csv'

diffDF = [pd.read_csv(p) for p in (Q1lineCount, Q2lineCount)]
merged_dataframe = pd.concat(diffDF, axis=1)
merged_dataframe.to_csv(merged_destination, index=False)


diffGenDF = pd.read_csv(merged_destination)

# getting Difference
diffGenDF ['Difference'] = diffGenDF ['Q1Count'] - diffGenDF ['Q2Count']
diffGenDF = diffGenDF [['Difference', 'Q1Count', 'Q1Names', 'Q2Count ', 'Q2Names']]

diffGenDF.to_csv(merged_destination, index=False)
```

So, making a space under `Q1Names` and adding a `0` under `Q1Count` in the same row where `pineapple` is under column `Q2Names` would make this easier to see an accurate difference between the values.

```
Q1Count              Q1Names               Q2Count                   Q2Names
2                      candy                     2                     candy
9                      apple                     8                     apple
0                                                5                 pineapple
10                     bread                    12                     bread
4                       pies                     4                      pies
3                    cookies                     3                   cookies
32                 chocolate                    27                 chocolate
[Total count: 60]                               [Total count: 61]
```

The final desired output I would get if I can get past that part is this:

```
Difference          Q1Count                  Q1Names          Q2Count                  Q2Names
0                         2                    candy                2                    candy
1                         9                    apple                8                    apple
-5                        0                                         5                pineapple
-2                       10                    bread               12                    bread
0                         4                     pies                4                     pies
0                         3                  cookies                3                  cookies
5                        32                chocolate               27                chocolate
                         [Total count: 60]                         [Total count: 61]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your same results using a `pd.merge` with the dataframe you provided

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'Q1Names', right_on = 'Q2Names', how = 'outer')
df_merge[['Q1Count', 'Q2Count']] = df_merge[['Q1Count', 'Q2Count']].fillna(0)
df_merge[['Q1Names', 'Q2Names']] = df_merge[['Q1Names', 'Q2Names']].fillna('')
df_merge['Difference'] = df_merge['Q1Count'].sub(df_merge['Q2Count'])
```

Comment: Thank you Arch! I added a little more on my end to work with my code. I converted the `Q1Count` and `Q2Count` columns to `int` using, for example, `df2=df2.astype({'Q2Count':'int'})` so the math could be done. Then I did the same with the `Difference` column to `int`. Then rewrote the csv file with this new data. Thank you so much again! :)